# GCM MismatchSenderId causes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know all causes which generate the MismatchSenderId error.
Because I cannot find what is the problem with my app. It successfuly received the Sender Id after execution of:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
....
```

But When I send the subscription.endpoint to server to push a notification message I always get this error MismatchSenderId

In the manifest.json I have entered the gcm number of my project from google console dashboard. I tried using server and browse Api keys. Tried many changes, and nothing works, my website uses 128 SSL. I cannot understand where is the problem.

What else I should check? I cannot understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the sender ID used to get the registration token not matching the server key used to push the message.

Go to the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) for your project, you should see a project number on the home screen. Use that when [getting a registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). Then in credentials on the developer console for the same project, generate a server API key, then use that for pushing messages.

If you use some different id when registering, or use the API key from a different developer console project, you will get the MismatchSenderId error.